# In a list of $n$ numbers, if a particular number appears more than $\frac n 3$ times, it will show up in subpartitions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am out of characters in the title, so here is the full question:

In a list of $n$ numbers such that $n = 2^k$, if a particular number appears more than $\frac n 3$ times, and we partition the list into 2 lists of even length, prove that the particular number will also appear more than $\frac {n} 6$ times in at least one of the sublists.

Example:

$$[1, 2,3,3,5,3, 6, 7]$$

The number $3$ appears more than $\frac 8 3$ times in the list. Furthermore, in some sublist (which are of size $4$), it will appear more than $\frac 1 3$ of the time in that sublist. For instance, the sublist $[1, 2, 3, 3]$ and $[5, 3, 6, 7]$, it appears more than $\frac 1 3$ of the time in the first sublist.

This intuitively makes sense to me, but how can I prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number appears less than $\frac {n}{6}$ in both subpartitions, then it appears less than $\frac {n}{3}$ in the original list.

Thus at least in one of the subpartitions, it appears $\ge \frac {n}{6}$ times but the equality is not an option because it is not an integer.

Therefore it appears in one of the subpartitions more than $\frac {n}{6} $times